# Facing issues when joining rows of A column data into single cell at B column of 1st row

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to bifurcate around 14900 rows of A column into 50 sets at each row in B column keeping @ as delimiter. Example: 12345@5432333@3232@... till 50th row of A column. Like that I need to build 50 sets till row count of A column(14900) in each row of B column.

I developed code for the same using =TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,A1:A14900) but this is failing, may be due to length issues in single cell. my plan is to break the output of this formula into 50 sets and place the same into each row of B column. if i use loop to make the formula dynamic then im worrying the length of cell again

```
    --------     --------
    12345566     12345566@333344444@98ZBRE322@1ZAZAZAQQ...till 50th row
    333344444    next 50 sets
    98ZBRE322    next 50 sets
    1ZAZAZAQQ    next 50 sets
```

Is there any best way to solve this issue?

Comment: You could try with `INDIRECT`: `=TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,INDIRECT("A" & ((ROW()-1)*50+1) & ":A" & ((ROW()-1)*50+50)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concatenate Ranges

**Excel**

In cell `B1` use:

`INDEX`

```
=TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,INDEX(A$1:A$14900,(ROW()-1)*298+1):INDEX(A$1:A$14900,ROW()*298))
```

`OFFSET` (Volatile)

```
=TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,OFFSET(A$1:A$298,(ROW()-1)*298,0))
```

and copy down to cell `B50`.

**VBA**

```vb
Sub ConcatSets()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B50")
        ' INDEX
        .Formula = "=TEXTJOIN(""@"",TRUE,INDEX(A$1:A$14900,(ROW()-1)*298+1):INDEX(A$1:A$14900,ROW()*298))"
        ' OFFSET (Volatile)
        '.Formula = "=TEXTJOIN(""@"",TRUE,OFFSET($A$1:$A$298,(ROW()-1)*298,0))"
        ' To keep only values use the following:
        '.Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly :) Can you tell me how to pass the row count in place of 14900.I want to make my code dynamic, so that in future row count may be anything. so want to pass variable in this.

Comment: If you mean that you want to make the VBA code dynamic, then there are two many things to consider to cover this here. If you change `14900` you also have to change the `298`. Since `14900/50 = 298` it all went well, but what if it is not divisible,...etc. Best copy the (improved) code to another question and explain what it is doing and what you want it to be doing.